# Comparing to Server API for Synching

Tags: ios, json, core-data, synchronization

I need to synch up Core Data on phone with MYSQL database on server.  I have gotten as far as capturing JSON feed in iOS in array.  My question is, what is the best way to compare and sync up the items?

I know there are many SO posts and tutorials on syncing however the comparison is often brushed over.  Once you have the JSON feed in an array and also have a managed object context, how do you compare one entry against the other?

My strategy is to give each locally saved object (record) a local id.  Then when syncing occurs if the local object (record) has no server id, add it to the server table.  However, I'm not sure how that works with the managed object context.

Do you iterate through the local records and compare them against server records?

Or do you iterate through the JSON array against the local managed object context?

```
for (NSDictionary *item in names) {
    id serverid = [item objectForKey:@"serverid"];

    // .... check against something in managed objectcontext
    if (!items.serverid ) { 
        ///insert on server and also provide obtained serverid to managedobjectcontext
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any insights or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Isted addressed a similar issue in [his exceptional talk at WWDC 2013](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013-211/).

You should watch the whole thing, because it's pretty awesome.  However, the relevant part for this topic starts about 12:43 into the presentation.